# Why is RSACryptoServiceProvider.Encrypt() output not stable?

Tags: .net, cryptography, rsa, rsacryptoserviceprovider, pkcs#1

Until today I was living under the impression that RSA encryption using RSA is deterministic. After all, how should signature verification work if it wasn't?

To my big suprise, .NETs `RSACryptoServiceProvider` does not have a stable output when encrypting the same set of bytes with the same keys:

```
[Fact]
public void Learning()
{
    const int keySize = 1024;

    System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider(keySize);

    var bytes = GenerateRandomDataWithLength( 36 );

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        Assert.Equal( rsa.Encrypt( bytes, false ), rsa.Encrypt( bytes, false ) );
}

byte[] GenerateRandomDataWithLength( int length )
{
    Random r = new Random();

    byte[] data = new byte[length];
    r.NextBytes( data );

    return data;
}
```

I have skimmed through the [PKCS Specification](http://www.rsa.com/rsalabs/node.asp?id=2125) and I do understand the math behind RSA, so I really wonder why I am observing the output to be unstable.

Mono's RSA implementation has a stable output. The unstable output of `Encrypt` does not affect decryption, which is well possible and yields the expected data.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

RSA encryption is pure mathematic so it will give you the same result everytime. However calling `Encrypt` in .NET is not simply doing RSA encryption.

**Why ?** The PKCS#1 padding (default when you use `false` in `Encrypt`) will make every encrypted result different because it includes random data (for padding purpose).

Mono has the **same** behavior (at least on my system, see note). However if you are using `EncryptValue`, which Mono supports but .NET does not (CryptoAPI limitation), then **no** padding will be done and the encrypted result will be identical each time.

**Note:** If you have different results please fill a bug report on http://bugzilla.xamarin.com and include the version number you are using.

Comment: Alright, I did completely forget padding included random data. You are clearly right here. Thanks for your answer! (The mono version I was refering to was _very_ old, it was just the sources for Monos RSA actually).

Comment: @Johannes Note that some random padding is needed to make RSA encryption secure against chosen-plaintext attacks (i.e. encrypting a guessed plaintext again to see if the output matches the one intercepted before).

Comment: For clarity I would add that using `true` in `Encrypt` results in random padding as well, I believe (`OAEP`).